# Assigning a variable inside of a block requires weak reference?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsdictionary, objective-c-blocks

So I have the following code:

```
[serviceHandler getHomeConfigurationData:^(NSDictionary *data){
        if (data) {
            NSLog(@"The Data: %@", data);
            homeConfigData = data;
        }
    } failure:^(NSError *error, BaseServiceHandler *context){
        homeConfigData = Nil;
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

in here, `homeConfigData` is an instance variable in my ViewController. This entire method is done on a background thread. It's possible that the ViewController is deallocated once the completion block returns / is fired. So I'm worried if I'll get an issue when I do the line `homeConfigData = data;`

How would I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

> It's possible that the ViewController is deallocated once the
>   completion block returns / is fired.

Actually, as it is written now, it is *not* possible that the ViewController is deallocated by the time the block runs, because both of those blocks retain `self` as `self` is used in both blocks (because the instance variable `homeConfigData` is used, which implicitly means `self->homeConfigData`).

Comment: Interesting. So if the `getHomeConfigurationData` method (which is a method call) takes 1 min to fire back and the containing ViewController there is no chance for it to be deallocated?

Comment: @user1416564: yes

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
YourClass *__weak weakSelf = self;

[serviceHandler getHomeConfigurationData:^(NSDictionary *data){
    if (data) {
        NSLog(@"The Data: %@", data);
        weakSelf.homeConfigData = data;
    }
} failure:^(NSError *error, BaseServiceHandler *context){
    weakSelf.homeConfigData = Nil;
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

If all of the strong pointers to self become nil, the instance will be deallocated and all the weak pointers, i.e. `weakSelf`, will become nil.  Sending the `setHomeConfigData` selector to nil will be a noop.

Comment: if weakSelf becomes nil, do we get Nil = data. Is this going to cause a crash? 

Also, am I correct in assuming I should be doing this?

Also I cannot do weakSelf.homeConfigData because "homeConfigData" is an instance variable

Comment: I'm not following your concerns.  `weakSelf` should be a pointer to an instance, so using an instance variable shouldn't be an issue.  `data` will not be nil, but `weakSelf.homeConfigData = data` will be a no-op because `weakSelf` will be nil.  If you're having further issues, post more code.

Comment: Okay, let me try again. `homeConfigData` is a private variable. This means that you cannot do `self.homeConfigData`. It won't compile. Anyway, I managed to figure out a solution and just declare `homeConfigData` by using `__block` in front.